# How to init workflow from setup recipe in OrchardCMS

Tags: workflow, orchardcms, recipe

I set up a workflow in dev and export it to a single recipe. And I copy and past the "Workflows" section to a setup recipe then select this recipe when install a new Orchard website.

But the installation could not completed by blow error:

> [SQL: select workflowde0_.Id as Id209_, workflowde0_.Enabled as Enabled209_, workflowde0_.Name as Name209_ from Orchard_Workflows_WorkflowDefinitionRecord workflowde0_ where workflowde0_.Name=@p0] ---> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The specified table does not exist. [ Orchard_Workflows_WorkflowDefinitionRecord ]

I know I can import the exported recipe after the installation completed using Import/Export module. But I want to set up the inital data in the installation stage as set up the Roles info which success from setup recipe

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT
From discussions in the comments we worked out it was that workflow imports need to be placed after the migrations section.

ORIGINAL
It sounds like you haven't enabled the workflow module. You can add Orchard.Workflows to the comma separated list of features to enable in your set up recipe.

Comment: I thought it was reason. But I have check the setup recipe. Orchard.Workflows feature is enabled and other enabled feature depencies on Orchard.Workflows as well. I still check the database table. The weird thing is that the table with name Orchard_Workflows_WorkflowdefinitionRecord had been created.

Comment: Interesting, I'm sure I have done workflows in a set up recipe. I will try and dig one out. Did it error on set up or   was that error in the logs? What version of orchard are you working on?

Comment: The setup can run to the end. But the orchard always gives me "tenant is currently intialing" message when access the site. So I checked the log and got that error message. I used version 1.10.1 and database is sqlce

Comment: Can you share your recipe? Mine ran fine on 1.10.1. Here is my recipe: https://pastebin.com/F6V4Z3cy

Comment: Thanks for your raw recipe. I compare mine with yours and find the point. My workflow section is located before the Migration section which yours is located after that. And I move my section after Migration as well, then it works.

Comment: Cool, I updated my answer with how you fixed it, for anyone stumbling across the same problem